Deploying your local App via docker compose to Azure as Azure Web app
We have a application containing two modules. we have successfully run it in local however when we push our images to azure ACR and then from there try to deploy as web app our container residing inside webapp terminating. althoug we have enabled application logs, we can not see the underlying reason behind this failure. we can reach app logs via ftp but the same logs we see as we see in azure deployment logs. How can we see the underlying reason of this web app failure especially the container error of app

2024_11_24_lw1sdlwk0007II_default_docker.log:
2024_11_24_lw1sdlwk0007II_docker.log:
2024-11-24T12:47:45.8718143Z Container start method called.
2024-11-24T12:47:45.8813825Z Establishing network.
2024-11-24T12:47:45.8814890Z Pulling image: baseqappregistry.azurecr.io/baseq-main-backend:v1.0.0.
2024-11-24T12:47:47.1227294Z Container is starting.
2024-11-24T12:47:47.1227766Z Establishing user namespace if not established already.
2024-11-24T12:47:47.1228129Z Establishing network if not established already.
2024-11-24T12:47:47.1228377Z Mounting volumes.
2024-11-24T12:47:47.1317658Z Nested mountpoint
2024-11-24T12:47:47.1522772Z Nested mountpoint volatile/logs
2024-11-24T12:47:47.1632464Z Nested mountpoint
2024-11-24T12:47:47.2121472Z Nested mountpoint
2024-11-24T12:47:47.2325847Z Nested mountpoint
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6205926Z Creating container.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6217898Z Creating pipes for streaming container io.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6406468Z Creating stdout named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stdout_47f2c01275b1408a9bbbb3f567b90358.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6426624Z Successfully created stdout named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stdout_47f2c01275b1408a9bbbb3f567b90358.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6427590Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stdout_47f2c01275b1408a9bbbb3f567b90358 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6427991Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stdout_47f2c01275b1408a9bbbb3f567b90358.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6428181Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stdout_47f2c01275b1408a9bbbb3f567b90358.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6516030Z Creating stderr named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stderr_1b6059ad7f49434eab65640ba087cfc3.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6517442Z Successfully created stderr named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stderr_1b6059ad7f49434eab65640ba087cfc3.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6517647Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stderr_1b6059ad7f49434eab65640ba087cfc3 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6517982Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stderr_1b6059ad7f49434eab65640ba087cfc3.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6518160Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f/stderr_1b6059ad7f49434eab65640ba087cfc3.
2024-11-24T12:47:48.6518406Z Creating container with image: baseqappregistry.azurecr.io/baseq-main-backend:v1.0.0 from registry: baseqappregistry.azurecr.io and fully qualified image name: baseqappregistry.azurecr.io/baseq-main-backend:v1.0.0
2024-11-24T12:47:49.5239070Z Starting container: baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f.
2024-11-24T12:47:49.6259775Z Starting watchers and probes.
2024-11-24T12:47:49.6455333Z Starting metrics collection.
2024-11-24T12:47:49.6468608Z Container is running.
2024-11-24T12:47:49.8856051Z Container start method finished after 4003 ms.
2024-11-24T12:47:50.1262212Z Container has finished running with exit code: 0.
2024-11-24T12:47:50.1279971Z Container is terminating. Grace period: 5 seconds.
2024-11-24T12:47:50.1366823Z Stop and delete container. Retry count = 0
2024-11-24T12:47:50.1371153Z Stopping container: baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f.
2024-11-24T12:47:50.2285988Z Deleting container: baseqbackendapp_a3b2fe8f. Retry count = 0
2024-11-24T12:47:51.2204620Z Container spec TerminationMessagePolicy path
2024-11-24T12:47:51.2205486Z Container is terminated. Total time elapsed: 1085 ms.
2024-11-24T12:47:51.2205729Z Site container: baseqbackendapp terminated during site startup.
2024-11-24T12:47:51.2704159Z Site startup probe failed after 1.3213503 seconds.
2024-11-24T12:47:51.3195764Z Failed to start site. Revert by stopping site.
2024-11-24T12:47:52.1416495Z Site: baseqbackendapp stopped.
2024-11-24T12:47:56.297Z INFO - Pulling image: baseqappregistry.azurecr.io/baseq-main-backend:v1.0.0
2024-11-24T12:47:56.645Z INFO - v1.0.0 Pulling from baseq-main-backend
2024-11-24T12:47:56.748Z INFO - Digest: sha256:26e398971b66c929ace491e18826505c8098d7d34bcb0580639e61187bee3a33
2024-11-24T12:47:56.752Z INFO - Status: Image is up to date for baseqappregistry.azurecr.io/baseq-main-backend:v1.0.0
2024-11-24T12:47:56.763Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Seconds
2024-11-24T12:47:56.975Z INFO - Starting container for site
2024-11-24T12:47:56.976Z INFO - docker run -d --expose=80 --name baseqbackendapp_0_dd6d23aa -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=false -e DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME=baseq-main-backend:v1.0.0 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=baseqbackendapp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=baseqbackendapp.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=e55efd6783db50fae15b26e5ec67d28845ef537db278e9c1346becd2b2f1a777 baseqappregistry.azurecr.io/baseq-main-backend:v1.0.0
2024-11-24T12:47:56.977Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2024-11-24T12:48:02.223Z INFO - Initiating warmup request to container baseqbackendapp_0_dd6d23aa for site baseqbackendapp
2024-11-24T12:48:02.316Z ERROR - Container baseqbackendapp_0_dd6d23aa for site baseqbackendapp has exited, failing site start
2024-11-24T12:48:02.631Z ERROR - Container baseqbackendapp_0_dd6d23aa didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-11-24T12:48:02.832Z INFO - Stopping site baseqbackendapp because it failed during startup.

below is docker-compose
version: "3.8"

networks:
  xapp:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  xapp_dev:

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      target: base
    ports:
      - "7377:7377"
    environment:
      ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "${ALLOWED_ORIGINS:-http://localhost:7377,http://0.0.0.0:7377,http://localhost:5173,http://127.0.0.1:5173}"
    working_dir: /home/xapp/backend
    command: ["bash", "-c", "python -m alembic upgrade head && python -m uvicorn xapp.main:app --port=7377 --host=0.0.0.0 --reload"]
    volumes:
      - xapp_dev:/home/.xapp 
      - ./backend/xapp:/home/xapp/backend/xapp
      - ./backend/alembic:/home/xapp/backend/alembic
    networks:
      - xapp

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/app/src
    networks:
      - xapp


and here dockerfile
# -------------------------------
# FRONTEND BUILD STAGE
# Build frontend build export dist folder 
# -------------------------------

FROM node:21-alpine AS temp-frontend
# Need python for node-gyp in building
RUN apk --update --no-cache add \
    libc6-compat \
    automake \
    libtool \
    autoconf \
    build-base \
    zlib \
    zlib-dev \
    python3 make gcc g++

WORKDIR /home/xapp/frontend
COPY frontend/package.json frontend/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY frontend/ .

ARG API_URL="/"

ENV VITE_API_URL=$API_URL
RUN npm run build
# -------------------------------


# -------------------------------
# BASE-BUILD IMAGE WITH BACKEND
# Build backend dependencies and install them
# -------------------------------
FROM python:3.11.6-slim-bookworm AS temp-backend

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /home/xapp/backend

# Setup for poetry
ENV PATH="/home/xapp/.poetry/bin:${PATH}" \
    POETRY_HOME="/home/xapp/.poetry"

# Don't buffer `stdout`:
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
# Don't create `.pyc` files:
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir poetry

# Install build dependencies, install dependencies, remove build dependencies
RUN apt-get clean && apt update --fix-missing && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install git libpq-dev build-essential -y

# Copy in poetry files only - this allows us to cache the layer if no new dependencies were added and install base deps
COPY backend/pyproject.toml backend/poetry.lock ./
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true && poetry install --only main --no-root


# -------------------------------
# BASE BUILD
# -------------------------------
FROM python:3.11.6-slim-bookworm AS base

WORKDIR /home/xapp

# Install postgres connector dependencies
RUN apt update && apt install --no-install-recommends libpq5 -y

# Move it to venv not .venv so supervisord does not cry
COPY --from=temp-backend /home/xapp/backend/.venv /home/xapp/backend/venv
ENV PATH="/home/xapp/backend/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Copy in backend files
WORKDIR /home/xapp/backend
COPY backend/*.py .
COPY backend/samples ./samples
COPY backend/xapp ./xapp
COPY backend/alembic ./alembic
COPY backend/templates ./templates
COPY backend/alembic.ini .

WORKDIR /home/xapp

RUN mkdir -p /home/.xapp

# Supervisord will forward the env vars to the subprocess envs
ENV SQLITE_PATH="/home/.xapp/db.sqlite3"
ENV DATA_DIRECTORY="/home/.xapp/data"

# -------------------------------
# SPA BUILD WITH MINIMAL DEPS
# -------------------------------
FROM base AS spa

WORKDIR /home/xapp/backend

# Copy in frontend build so we can serve it from FastAPI
COPY --from=temp-frontend /home/xapp/frontend/dist /home/xapp/frontend/dist
RUN \
    cp -r /home/xapp/frontend/dist/assets /home/xapp/backend && \
    cp /home/xapp/frontend/dist/favicon.ico /home/xapp/backend/assets && \
    cp /home/xapp/frontend/dist/.vite/manifest.json /home/xapp/backend/assets

# This stage is meant to be used as an SPA server with FastAPI serving a React build
ENV SPA_MODE=1
ARG ALLOWED_ORIGINS
ENV ALLOWED_ORIGINS=$ALLOWED_ORIGINS


# Running alembic and uvicorn without combining them in a bash -c command won't work
CMD ["bash", "-c", "python -m xapp.main"]



Please specify the framework of your app.

Ensure Port 80 is Exposed in Dockerfile.

Share your dockerfile here.

@AsleshaKantamsetti shared now in the question.

It's expecting your app to run on port 80. I suspect it's not.

@Türkmen Mustafa Demirci Include EXPOSE 80 in your Dockerfile.

@Türkmen Mustafa Demirci Change the port in the Docker Compose file to use port 80.


2024-11-24T12:48:02.316Z ERROR - Container baseqbackendapp_0_dd6d23aa for site baseqbackendapp has exited, failing site start
2024-11-24T12:48:02.631Z ERROR - Container baseqbackendapp_0_dd6d23aa didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-11-24T12:48:02.832Z INFO - Stopping site baseqbackendapp because it failed during startup.

Even I got the same error when I used the Port 7377 in docker-compose.yml  and I changed port to 80.
Azure expects the container to listen on port 80 by default for HTTP traffic. So, the container is mapped to a different port, Azure cannot successfully connect to the application.
docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    image: backend-app:latest
    container_name: backend-app
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:password@db:5432/backend_db"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app_network
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: backend-db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: backend_db
    networks:
      - app_network

Make Sure to Expose Port 8000 in dockerfile.
Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

Azure Web App Output:



@Türkmen Mustafa Demirci Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with
